# Converting file to dict

Tags: python, string, file, dictionary

How would I take the contents of the file and change it into a dictionary?
The contents would include menu items in this form:

```
1 Chocolate ice cream
2 Green tea
 8 Shrimp roll
```

And I want the key to be the number and the value to be the food item.

So far, I got:

```
d = {}
for line in menu.read().strip().split():
      d[line[0]] = d[line[1:]]
return d
```

But this comes out skewed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop over the file object, line by line, then split the lines:

```
with open('inputfilename.txt') as menu:
    d = {}
    for line in menu:
        key, value = line.split(None, 1)
        d[key] = value.strip()
    return d
```

The `.split(None, 1)` call applies the default split algorithm (split on arbitrary-width whitespace), but limits it to just *one* split to return just 2 items. The advantage is that lines that *start* with whitespace (such as the `' 8 Shrimp roll'` line in your post) are handled correctly too as the leading whitespace is removed before splitting.

This produces:

```
{'2': 'Green tea', '1': 'Chocolate ice cream', '8': 'Shrimp roll'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
d = {}
for line in menu.read().strip().split():
      d[line[0]] = line[1:] # you want to use just line[1:], than d[line[1:]]
return d
```

The issue here is that `d[line[1:]]` gives you the value mapped by the key `line[1:]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> finalDict = {}
>>> with open('fileName.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            key, elem = line.strip().split(" ", 1)
            finalDict[int(key)] = elem


>>> finalDict
{8: 'Shrimp roll', 1: 'Chocolate ice cream', 2: 'Green tea'}
```

We iterate over each line of the file, stripping it, then splitting it on the first space.

Answer (score 2):

How about a dictionary comprehension?

```
{ k:v.strip() for k, v in (line.split(None, 1) for line in menu) }
```